# Laravel Migrations x Flyway Migrations

Tags: php, sql, laravel, flyway

I worked with CodeIgniter as PHP framework and Flyway to migrate the .sql code in a project for the past 2 years. It worked very well and I recommend it.

However, a new project needs to use the Laravel as framework. So, when I studied Laravel, I saw it has a migrations functionality.

Did somebody work with both and can tell the advantages and disadivantages of each one?

In my research, I found the list bellow:

Laravel:
- less painfull if you want to move from mysql to postresql or other database;
- it is possible to use raw SQL, however, it is unnatural;
- if you change the PHP Framework, you will need to move the migrations strategy;

Flyway
- Very easy to use;
- It uses only raw SQL, with all its advantages;
- Keep the PHP and the database code separated;
- Its painfull to change from mysql to others databases;

Now, I'm using Mysql and Jenkins, for automation.

Any more suggestions?

Comment: From your description - and I have to admit I don't know anything about Flyway - I would conclude that Laravel offers the more powerful system as you can basically do both?! If you wanted to use the Flyway approach within Laravel (plain `.sql` files), you could for example create a custom command that creates one or two `.sql` files (up and down) plus a migration file which does nothing else than executing these two files (and which doesn't require any manual changes). I would personally stick with framework conventions though, it makes the life of everyone easier (i.e. onboard process).

Comment: Another advantage of using Laravel migration is it's easier for writing DB unit test out of the box. e.g. the RefreshDatabase trait calls and tracks laravel migration behind the scene. Saying that though, I personally prefer flyway. Just the fact of separating sql vs code is already a big plus. Practically you won't need to change DB in a real life project often, and having to learn another set of syntax to do the same thing is too much of an overhead for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use both. Flyway is powerful when you want to track schema changes over time and ensure that these changes will not break your production environment. It also offers some security in your production environments, preventing DB upgrades from occurring when some 'clever' devops person has modified the production database to 'fix' a problem.

Ensuring that db changes are tracked, verified and applied  in the proper order is what makes it so powerful. And you, the developer, do not have to write a bunch of infrastructure around tracking schema changes in the database itself. Flyway handles that for you.

That being said, it might not be the best/easiest/most convenient for inserting data during the test cycle(s). A hybrid approach may be easier but I have incorporated flyway even in a java/spring environment to validate schema changes and to populate test data.

Developers often have to make schema changes and flyway is superb at providing an infrastructure which prevents conflicts and makes the road smooth and verifiable.

Because of its versioning in the database, one can audit changes and verify the version of the current database - ie, what schema changes have been applied and when. I can't tell you how many times I've worked on software projects which had no such tracking. This made it impossible to determine what state the database was in without a bunch of queries and investigation. Often before discovering flyway, developers in projects I've been involved with rolled their own database versioning because without it, it was impossible to know if the person deploying the software had left out a step thus causing the upgrade to fail. "oh! I forgot to run the sql script that added the new column constraints!"

Flyway takes all of that uncertainty and makes it certain. If Laravel's migrate features are as robust as flyway's probably it's best to use what comes in the framework. But it may not and a hybrid approach would give you the best overall peace of mind.